# Setting a macro variable with if then statement in SAS/WPS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to set a macro variable using an if then statement using SAS programming language but using WPS (World Programming System), which is basically a SAS clone, but for some reason it's not working.

```
%if 1=1 %then %do;
    data test;
    a=111;
    run;

    %let a=2;
%end;

%put &a.;
```

I get this message after the put statement:

```
WARNING: Macro variable "&a" was not resolved
```

However, the test dataset was successfully created. Is this just a WPS specific problem, or does the same error occur in SAS as well?

Update: I tried running the above code within a macro, but I still get the same error message:

```
%macro test_macro();
%if 1=1 %then %do;
    data test;
    a=111;
    run;

    %let a=2;
%end;
%mend;

%test_macro();
%put &a.;
```

Comment: Is that code in a macro or open code?  Are you using SAS or WPS?  If SAS what version of SAS are you using (including the maintenance level).  You need to have at least the 9.4M5 release of SAS.  https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2018/07/05/if-then-else-sas-programs/

Comment: @Tom This is open code and its WPS. The if then statement seems to be working in open code as the data step works. Does my code work in newer SAS versions?

Comment: @Tom Just tried to run it within a macro and I get the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't tell the macro processor that you want A to be a global macro symbol it will be made in the local macro symbol table.

Either define A before calling the macro:

```
%let a=before macro call;
%test_macro();
%put &a.;
```

Or add a %GLOBAL statement inside the macro definition.

```
%macro test_macro();
  %global a;
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestions with and without a macro and it works in both situations.

Comment: I would add that you should always use the second (`%global`) if you are intending to export a macro value this way.  (In fact, I'd say that you should define every single macro variable as `%local` or `%global` to avoid the first case occurring - i.e., you overwrite a global macro variable you're not intending to.)

Comment: Indiscriminate use of %GLOBAL can also cause problems when the name already is in use in some other active scope. You can use conditional logic to only generate %GLOBAL when it is actually needed.  `%if not %symexit(a) %then %global a;`